# foreach statement fails in CMS application, error message says invalid argument

Tags: php

In the CMS i'm working on I'm using a foreach statement to display the returned database results.

but ever page load I get an error message saying the foreach statement im using has an invalid argument

here's the statement

```
       <?php foreach ( $presults as $post ) {  ?>

        <!-- Post Frames -->



            <div class="outerPost_frame">

                <div class="postScreen"> 

                    <!--post date hidden show on hover -->
                    <span class="date_">
                        <p><?php echo date('j F', $post->date) ?></p>
                    </span>

                    <!-- post title -->
                    <span class="name_">
                        <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post->name) ?></p>
                    </span>


                    <span class="content_">
                        <?php echo $results['post']->content ?>
                    </span>    

                </div>
            </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire error, and tell us which line is erroring?

Comment: Try var_dump($presults) and see what the data structure looks like. Make sure it's an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting $presults to an array.

```
<?php foreach ( (array) $presults as $post ) {  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting up your array, could be a problem, but we would need an error msg to know for sure.

Try this though

```
<?php foreach ( $presults as $post ) {  ?>

    <!-- Post Frames -->



        <div class="outerPost_frame">

            <div class="postScreen"> 

                <!--post date hidden show on hover -->
                <span class="date_">
                    <p><?php echo date('j F', $post[date]) ?></p>
                </span>

                <!-- post title -->
                <span class="name_">
                    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post[name]) ?></p>
                </span>


                <span class="content_">
                    <?php echo $post[content] ?>
                </span>    

            </div>
        </div>

<?php } ?>
```